# Is there a way to access jwt user information in unprotected endpoint in nodejs using express-jwt?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm using express-jwt to protect my endpoints, but I'd like an unprotected endpoint to show some extra information if the user is logged in. So I'm wondering if there is a way to access such user info in unprotected endpoint?

codes look like:

```js
// unprotected endpoint
router.get('/:productId', function(req, res) {
    // some ways to get user info??
    if (req.user.userId) {
        // add some extra fields into returning_data
        // something like purchase history
    }
    res.json({data: returning_data})
}
```

Or if there is an alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [code for express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/blob/master/lib/index.js) it appears that if you pass the option `credentialsRequired: false` on your express-jwt setup for the routes you want, it should allow access even if the token is not present.

Therefore, for example:

```
var expjwt = require('express-jwt');

app.use('/private', expjwt({ secret: "sssshhhhh!" }), apiRoutesPrivate);
app.use('/public', apiRoutesPublic);
app.use('/publicwithuser', expjwt({ secret: "sssshhhhh!", credentialsRequired: false }), apiRoutesPublicWithUser);
```

... where apiRoutesPrivate / Public / PublicWithUser contain the relevant routes for each.